# ImportError: No module named json

Tags: python, json, simplejson

While installing a c++ library I ran into a Python problem (and I do not know nothing about this language). While running some Python code the shell gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\C++_libraries\v8\tools\dev\v8gen.py", line 54, in <module>
    import mb
  File "C:\C++_libraries\v8\tools\mb\mb.py", line 37, in <module>
    import json
ImportError: No module named json
```

I am using python 2.7.6 and I'm almost sure json is installed - I have a folder Lib/json containing the following files:

```
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  decoder.py  decoder.pyc  encoder.py  encoder.pyc  scanner.py  scanner.pyc  tool.py
```

When I run `import json` from the cmd it seems to work:

```
c:\C++_libraries\v8\tools\dev>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> print(json.__file__)
C:\depot_tools\python276_bin\lib\json\__init__.pyc
```

I tried substituting the code line `import json` with `import simplejson as json` but then it says

> no module named simplejson

(of course I also installed `simplejson`). I really do not know what else I can try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you overwriting `json` anywhere before you import it?

Comment: No what do you mean with overwriting json? (thank you for commenting btw)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. Although all the path variables were pointing to the right folders, windows was running python with a version that was installed within Lyx (that I did not know was there) and which did not have many of the Python modules. I managed to fix this from the control panel.